# How can I gracefully close my app when the EC2 instance is shut down?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, winforms, amazon-ec2

I have a data processing app which takes many hours to run. One of our customers is running it on an AWS EC2 Windows 2012 instance which has a shutdown schedule defined. As a result, it keeps getting cut off part way through each run.

This doesn't pose a problem for the data processing itself: each data row is processed atomically, and it can be safely restarted afterwards without re-doing any of the data rows already processed. However, it does write lots of summary data to disk at the end of the process, which I could really do with seeing, and this data is not getting written.

The app is written in VB.NET WinForms. There is a form that displays progress on screen, and the processing logic is done via a `BackgroundWorker` component.

The form handles cancellation events as follows:

```
Private Sub MyBase_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing

    ' If the user tried to close the app, ask if they are sure, and if not, then don't close down.
    If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing AndAlso ContainsFocus AndAlso Not PromptToClose() Then
        e.Cancel = True
        Return
    End If

    ' If the background worker is running, then politely request it to stop. Otherwise, let the form close down.
    If worker.IsBusy Then
        If Not worker.CancellationPending Then
            worker.CancelAsync()
        End If
        e.Cancel = True
    Else
        Environment.ExitCode = AppExitCode.Cancelled
    End If

End Sub
```

The background thread polls for cancellation once per data row processed, as follows:

```
Private Sub ReportProgress(state as UIState)
    worker.ReportProgress(0, state)
    If worker.CancellationPending Then
        Throw New AbortException ' custom exception type
    End If
End Sub
```

The top-level `Catch` block in the background thread handles all success and failure paths appropriately, writing all summary data to disk, before exiting the thread.

I have tested this extensively outside AWS. In particular, I have verified that, if you end the process via Task Manager, then it gracefully shuts down straight away without prompting the user, and writes all summary data to disk as expected. The graceful shutdown takes a few seconds at most.

My problem is, the summary data is not written to disk when AWS shuts down the EC2 instance on schedule. I don't know exactly what happens during the EC2 shutdown process, and my searching of the EC2 documentation has not yet shed light on this. I guess it could be one of:

- AWS or Windows is terminating running processes without sending `WM_CLOSE` messages
- AWS or Windows is giving insufficient time to each process to shut down

Can anyone clarify how the EC2 shutdown process works, or suggest how I can improve my code to handle it?

Comment: Have you tried handling the [SystemEvents.SessionEnding Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: @TnTinMn Thank you. I will try that, and see if I can grab an EC2 instance for myself to test it.

Comment: This sounds like a good solution as well: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html